# Font-Rendering difference with PhantomJS on Ubuntu/OSX

Tags: macos, ubuntu, fonts, rendering, phantomjs

I'm using PhantomJS (v1.9) to generate a pdf out of a website. The output look fine on OS X, but the font looks poor when using the same script on Ubuntu.

It's a custom FontFace (Source Sans Pro), but the same happens when using other (standard) fonts. I attached an image to show the difference. OS X on the left and Ubuntu on the right. Left is how it should look.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [electerious.com](https://l.electerious.com/uploads/big/20854e52c7450e6b3e7669f39944d6ee.jpg))</sub>

As I'm not an expert when it comes to font-rendering and differences between operating systems, let me know if additional informations are needed.

Anyone how knows how to improve the rendering or is this a common problem which can't be fixed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to begin with searching for system fonts supported on Ubuntu and determine which one is closest to the one you like. Going from Ubuntu to OSX yields better results. If a font is missing in Ubuntu, you can convert your Mac .dfont files to Ubuntu .ttf files,

```
sudo apt-get install fondu

fondu Helvetica.dfont // This generates ttf files

/usr/share/fonts/truetype // Move fonts files into Ubuntu
```

Reference: http://grasshopperpebbles.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-convert-mac-dfont-files-into-ttf-using-fondu/